# Как правильно написать: "Рыба, запеченная в омлете"?

Tags: пунктуация

С запятой после слова "рыба" или без запятой?

Answer (score 3):

Название ли это блюда, не название - на пунктуацию это не влияет.

Возможны следующие варианты пунктуации-орфографии (коментарии - личное мнение):
*Рыба, запеченная в омлете* - рыбу запекали в омлете.   
*Рыба запеченная, в омлете* - рыбу запекли, добавили омлет как гарнир, "омлет" -  уточнение.
*Рыба запеченная в омлете* - рыбу запекли, потом положили в омлет, омлет - часть блюда (= запеченная рыба в омлете).

В принципе грамматика допускает и вариант
*Рыба запеченная(,) в омлете*, где запеченная - одиночное причастие, но обычно в подобных случаях рекомендуют его рассматривать как отглагольное прилагательное, поскольку смыслового различия здесь нет или почти нет.

ЗЫ *Вас смущает возможность вынесения в название блюда причастного оборота?* Это вопрос интересный, но к русскому языку он прямого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Спсаибо огромное за подробный ответ !!!

Answer (score 1):

"Запеченная в омлете" - это причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, поэтому запятая обязательно нужна

Comment: То, что это причастный оборот я знаю. Сомнения берут, что это название блюда...

Comment: Но Вы ведь о запятой спрашивали!

Answer (score 0):

"запеченная в омлете" - это причастный оборот, "рыба" - определяемое слово, которое находится перед причастным оборотом. В таких случаях запятая ставится. Следовательно, надо оформить запись так:рыба, запеченная в омлете.

Comment: То, что это причастный оборот я знаю. Сомнения берут, что это название блюда...